# Can I run a 15 AMP heatbed behind a 5 AMP IEC Receptacle?

Tags: power-supply

I'm trying to build a cover for my Hypercube Evo's [Meanwell LRS 350W](https://www.jameco.com/z/LRS-350-24-MEAN-WELL-350-4W-24V-14-6A-Single-Output-Enclosed-Power-Supply_2219823.html) power supply.

The power supply input is 120V AC and it provides 24V DC output to a [Einsy Rambo 1.2](https://reprap.org/wiki/EinsyRambo) board.

I want to protect the Meanwell mains with a cover and a rocker switch with IEC receptacle like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KS2TQ45).

The receptacle has a 5 AMP Fuse between mains and switch.  The Einsy also has three fuses, one for Hotend 5 AMP and one for Fans, etc. 5 AMP, and also a 15 AMP fuse for the heatbed.  And there is a dedicated power input for the bed on the board. I plan to run a MK2a [heatbed](https://reprap.org/wiki/PCB_Heatbed), which I think will draw about 13 AMPS at least.

My question is, will the receptacle fuse blow when I use the heatbed, or does the amperage come from the power supply (after the receptacle)?

Any other thing I should worry about in this configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fuses on the board are for current pulled from the 24V DC. 15 amps of 24V DC is 3 amps of 120V AC, plus a little lost in conversion inefficiency in the power supply. If all of them were maxxed out, you'd be right at the 5 amp from mains, and inefficiency could perhaps throw you over. But presumably they're not supposed to be maxxed out, so you're probably okay.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the answer.